# Updated some code and now get this error - Cannot call value of non-function type "Any?!'

Tags: swift, xml, parsing

I am updating some code from Swift 2 that worked to Swift 3 and now I get this error message:

> Cannot call value of non-function type "Any?!"

I am parsing an xml rss feed and then loading different portions of it into a cell of a tableview. I have searched around  quite a bit but I cant find anyone doing exactly what I am doing and I havent been able to figure out the solution.

My code is;

```
cell.textLabel?.text = (feeds.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as AnyObject).object ("title") as! NSString
```

Here is all the code;

```
   //
//  TableViewController.swift
//  BRYHNH
//
//  Created by Bill Skrzypczak on 10/6/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Bill Skrzypczak. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit





// Define the class for the table view
// *****


class TableViewController: UITableViewController, XMLParserDelegate {



    // Step 1 - Define the variables, arrays, and dictionaries
    // *****

    var parser = XMLParser()              // Var for temp storage of parser data

    var feeds = NSMutableArray()            // Array for temp storage of episodes

    var elements = NSMutableDictionary()    // Dict for temp storage of episode elements

    var element = NSString()                // Var to hold data from current element

    var ftitle = NSMutableString()          // Var to hold current episode title

    var link = NSMutableString()            // Not sure I need this ???

    var fdescription = NSMutableString()    // Var to hold current episode song list

    var currentList = String()              // Var used to pass current song list thru segue

    var feedEnclosure = NSMutableString()   // Var used to store path of audio stream

    var mystream = NSMutableString()        // Var that will be used to store current audio stream


    // Run the parser methods when the App Starts up
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    // Step 2 - Setup the RSS Feed and Initialize the Parameters
    // *****
        feeds = []
        let url = URL(string: "http://www.bestradioyouhaveneverheard.com/podcasts/index.xml")
        _ = URLRequest(url:url! as URL)
        parser = XMLParser (contentsOf: url! as URL)!
        parser.delegate = self
        parser.shouldProcessNamespaces = false
        parser.shouldReportNamespacePrefixes = false
        parser.shouldResolveExternalEntities = false
        parser.parse()

    }

    // Step 3 -  Define your Methods/Functions
    // ***************************************

    // Initialize variables to "" when <item> tag is encountered
    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {

        element = elementName as NSString

        if (element as NSString).isEqual(to: "item") {
            elements = NSMutableDictionary()
            elements = [:]
            ftitle = NSMutableString()
            ftitle = ""
            link = NSMutableString()
            link = ""
            fdescription = NSMutableString()
            fdescription = ""
            mystream = NSMutableString()
            mystream = ""
            feedEnclosure = NSMutableString()
            feedEnclosure = ""


        }
        // Magic code to get enclosure url

        if elementName == "enclosure" {
            var attrsUrl = attributeDict as [String: NSString]
            let urlPic = attrsUrl["url"]
            elements.setObject(urlPic!, forKey: "enclosure" as NSCopying)

            //println(urlPic)
        }
    }

    // If the tag is not empty load a given key-value pair to the dictionary
    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {

        if (elementName as NSString).isEqual(to: "item") {

            if (ftitle != "") {
                elements.setObject(ftitle, forKey: "title" as NSCopying)
                //println(ftitle) // Confirm key-value pair loaded
            }

            if (link != "") {
                elements.setObject(link, forKey: "link" as NSCopying)
                //println(link) // Confirm key-value pair loaded
            }


            if (fdescription != "") {
                elements.setObject(fdescription, forKey: "itunes:summary" as NSCopying)
                //println(fdescription) // Confirm key-value pair loaded
            }

            if (feedEnclosure != "") {
                elements.setObject(feedEnclosure, forKey: "enclosure" as NSCopying)
                //println(feedEnclosure) // Confirm key-value pair loaded
            }


            feeds.add(elements)

        }

    }

    // Append the text from the element to the end of the receiver
    func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {


        if element.isEqual(to: "title"){
            ftitle.append(string)

        }else if element.isEqual(to: "link"){
            link.append(string)

        }else if element.isEqual(to: "itunes:summary"){
            fdescription.append(string)

        }

    }



    // Now reload all the data
    func parserDidEndDocument(_ parser: XMLParser) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }


    //  MARK ---> Define The Table View
    //


        // Define the number of sections in the tableview
        //
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }



        // Define the number of rows to display based on the number of items loaded into the array feeds
        //
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


        return feeds.count
    }



    // Populate the cell with data elements from parser Recycle the last cell
    //
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) 

        // Load an image file into the left margin
        //
         let image : UIImage = UIImage(named: "300px-banner.png")!
         cell.imageView?.image = image

        // Load the parser data from the title element
        //

        cell.textLabel?.text = (feeds.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as AnyObject).object ("title") as! NSString



        //        println(mystream)

        // Load 3 lines of data for each cell
        //
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 3

        return cell

    }

    // Only grab the data at the selected cell
    //

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


    }

    // Pass the data thru the segue
     func prepareForSegue(segue: (UIStoryboardSegue!), sender: AnyObject!) {
        if (segue.identifier == "mySegue") {

            // Set the path of the Segue to the other view controller 
            //
            let vc = segue.destination as! secondViewController
            let ms = segue.destination as! secondViewController

            // Set a constant to the current selected row
            //
            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {

                // Create a constant to hold the data you want to pass to the other view controller
                //
                let currentList = (feeds.object(at: indexPath.row) as AnyObject).object("itunes:summary") as! NSString
                //println(currentList)

                let mystream = (feeds.object(at: indexPath.row) as AnyObject).object("enclosure") as! NSString
                //println(mystream)

                // Load that data into a segue parameter that passes thru the segue
                //
                vc.toPass = currentList as String
                ms.audioStream = mystream as String


        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: How do you declare your `feeds`? Where do you declare your `object(_:)`?

Comment: Are you parsing your feed into a Feed object? or can you explain more what is the type of object your array holds please

Comment: Sorry here is the rest of the code. You can see how I set the objects in the parser function in the if statements.

Comment: I posted all the code above to make it clearer